# RODBC and sqlQueries with R objects

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I got a special problem I try to standadize SQL queries since they come up several times in my file.

An example.

at the top I want to define the column name and the table

```
Testquery <- c("COLUMN1")
Testtanle <- c("TABLE1")
```

Down the road in my code I want this to be implemented in a SQL query

```
Newvector<-sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT" Testquery "FROM" Testtanle)
```

Of course I run into problems with the `""`. Anyone an Idea how to handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for the `paste()` command or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking?

```
Newvector<-sqlQuery(channel, paste("SELECT", Testquery, "FROM", Testtanle))
```